# create a program with Xcode-like interface

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa

On Mac it is usual that there is a "hidden" main window.

The usual example is "Text Edit". When you open a file you with you don't see a "main frame". Instead every single file will be opened in its own "Text Edit" instance. This is OSX way of emulating the so-called MDI interface.

However, there is an exception. If you open Xcode and open the project there, you can click on the file and it will be open inside the main Xcode window. And if you double click the file it will be opened in its own independent editor window, keeping the main Xcode window visible.

My question would be: do I need to do anything special in order to make my program behave like an Xcode? Should I use different class for the main frame or maybe react differently on the opening document event?

Any hints/pointers where to look or even to the official Apple documentation would be helpful.

Comment: In Xcode, the project *is* the document and the files are simply resources within that document.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for what Apple sometimes called a "Shoebox" application? (like iPhoto, iTunes...) That search term might lead to a few more results.

Answer (score 4):

The TextEdit behavior you're describing is much more like “SDI” than “MDI”, and the terms “SDI” and “MDI” weren't even needed until Microsoft invented MDI long after Xerox invented the SDI-type interface of which macOS is a derivative.

Anyway, I think you are misunderstanding Xcode's behavior. You seem to think “its own independent editor window” is a different kind of window than “the main Xcode window”. But in fact the new window is of the same kind as the old window, with some optional parts hidden. You can show those hidden parts and make the new window look exactly like the old window. Demo:

[image]

The ability to open multiple windows showing the same document (or, in Xcode's case, project) is a matter of software architecture. If you carefully design your app so that multiple windows can share a single model object graph, and can be notified and redraw themselves when the object graph changes, then you have an app that supports multiple windows showing the same document. If you want multiple kinds of windows showing the same document, nothing about Cocoa stands in your way. As a matter of fact, Xcode *does* have at least one other kind of window in which it shows some properties of a project:

[image: project setting sheet]

That project settings sheet is really another window; macOS keeps it attached to the main window, but it is in fact an instance of `NSWindow` (or a subclass of `NSWindow`), no doubt with its own custom window controller that references the same project objects as the main window.

If you use the Cocoa `NSDocument` architecture, then a small amount of multi-window support is built-in: an `NSDocument` knows about its associated windows (via their window controllers). If you want to use the `NSDocument` architecture, you should read [*Document-Based App Programming Guide for Mac*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179-CH1-SW1).

Comment: what I'm after is the interface where all those sources are open inside the main frame - i.e. MDI interface.

Comment: macOS has no built-in support for implementing an MDI interface. You will have to implement the interior “windows” as views and implement the interior window frames (title bar, move/resize controls, close box) yourself.

Comment: I don't need the actual MDI as MS understands it. I will be satisfied with the Xcode-like interface where I can open multiple documents and those documents will  be located inside one big frame - scenario I explained in my OP when I click the mouse once.

Comment: I guess you're talking about a master/detail interface. Lots of macOS apps use a master/detail interface in a single window, such as Messages, iTunes, Photos, and Console. There's no special support for it in Cocoa, but if you're using Cocoa Bindings, there's a [chapter in *Cocoa Bindings Programming Topics*](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaBindings/Tasks/masterdetail.html) about it.

Answer (score 2):

It is unclear what you are after. The traditional Mac UI has been one window per document - i.e. SDI with a single instance of the app running multiple windows - but there has always been the ability for any app to organise the content of that window as it sees fit, including showing multiple "documents" within one window - i.e MDI type UI.

Apps approach such "MDI" in different ways, e.g. some use panes (views) and others tabs. From macOS Sierra the standard `NSWindow` supports tabs, this system is (semi)automatic for standard document apps. Read Apple's [NSWindow Automatic Window Tabbing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/AppKit/RN-AppKit/#10_12Window%20Tabbing) section in the Sierra release notes for more details.

If you wish to use multiple panes - e.g. like Xcode - you just use views (`NSView`) and arrange them how you wish.

HTH

Comment: what I'm after is the interface where I can open multiple documents inside the one big frame. In my explanation it is a scenario with one mouse click.