# Making Xcode like interface

Tags: macos, user-interface, cocoa

ALL,

in the OSX there 2 possible interfaces.

When you run the Text Edit and you open the new document- a brand new window will be open.
There is no main frame - all documents are open in its own window.

However when you run Xcode, open the project and then in the project pane select the file, not double click it, this file will be opened inside Xcode. No new window will be opened.

What I'd like to knowis how to make Xcode like interface where I have one main frame and all documents are opening inside.

Is there a documentation/guide/instructions on how to make it work. I'm working on the program where this interface makes more sense.

TIA!!

EDIT: I presume the down vote is because I'm seeking documentation/guidance. But I don't even know what to Google.

Comment: Xcode does some special stuff, but the crux of it is just the regular window tabbing that macOS does out-of-the-box. See [`NSWindow.allowsAutomaticWindowTabbing`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1646657-allowsautomaticwindowtabbing) and [`NSWindow.tabbingIdentifier`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1644704-tabbingidentifier). You just write your app as if each window is standalone, and the OS and user manage the tabbing themselves.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create a program with Xcode-like interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377468/create-a-program-with-xcode-like-interface). Found it on https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Making+Xcode+like+interface

Answer (score -2):

let try this

```
1. Open Xcode.
2. Go to **Xcode** menu at the top-left corner.
3. Click on **Preferences**.
4. In the Preferences window, select the **Navigation** tab.
5. Look for the **Navigation Style** section.
6. Here, you'll find an option called **Open tabs in place of windows**.
7. Check the box next to it.
```

Once you've done this, when you select a file in the project navigator and open it (not double-clicking), it should open within Xcode's main window as a new tab rather than in a separate window. This helps keep everything in one place for easier navigation and organization.

Comment: my question was about how to code such interface in Cocoaan not how to make it work inside Xcode.